# What are these SCSI connection types?

Tags: hard-drive, scsi

Simply put, what's the difference between these two SCSI connections?  The top one comes out of an IBM x Series server and the bottom one comes out of a Dell PowerEdge (I beleive).  Are these typical connections?  Are either proprietary?  Do they even use the same data spec (u320)?  It would be useful if I had a name to describe these different types of connections.  Thanks!

[image: SCSI Hard Drives]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty sure the top is a hot swap drive and the bottom one isn't. That's really the only difference. The top is called an SCA (single connector attachment) drive.

Answer (score 3):

Top drive is a SCSI SCA (Single connector attachment) drive
Bottom is a SCSI DB-68 drive